Programmatically getting the major/minor/patch details for a 1GP managed package from its packaging org
I have a collection of package version IDs for a 1GP managed package that I want to translate into major.minor.patch format details. I had expected to be able to do this using a Tooling API query of the form:
SELECT Id, MajorVersion, MinorVersion, PatchVersion FROM MetadataPackageVersion WHERE Id IN ('04t...', ...)

However, all I get back are the IDs themselves without the major, minor or patch version details. I cannot find why the details are not being returned - being tooling API there are no CRUD/FLS permissions at play, and my user has system admin profile.
Any idea how I can successfully retrieve these details from the packaging org for my 1GP managed package?

The query in question worked for me in Dev console without checking the tooling api check box.

The query works for me in developer console (only with 'tooling api' checked).  Did this in my developer org where a 1gp package exists.  The query results have data in the Id, MajorVersion, MinorVersion, PatchVersion

Thanks both. This is very weird; I do not know why it is not working for me - though I did not try the dev console - I was using an IDE. I will try the dev console...

This does, indeed, work in the packaging org's Developer Console as long as "Use Tooling API" is checked. I'm assuming there's an issue with the IDE I'm using and will raise an issue.

Now I'm struggling with how to save the results from Dev Console!

This query functions correctly through the Developer Console, selecting use of the Tooling API, though the results could not be exported - I had to jump a bunch of hoops to do that, saving the HTML source for the data table, stripping out the tag attributes, loading the resulting simple HTML file into Excel and copy/pasting the data over into the spreadsheet I needed to update.
I was using Illuminated Cloud as the IDE, and it turned out there was a bug with the version I was using (2.3.0.0) that caused this issue. This has been addressed in a later version (the query works with 2.3.1.4, for example).
